# Force foundation reveal to stay open unless button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation and Select2. When I select something within the select2 selector, my reveal closes. This happens when selecting from the dropdown list or clicking anywhere outside of the select. I don't know what is causing this and am already disabling `esc` and any other ways to close the reveal. I'm thinking that a good work around would be to just have it so that the modal can only ever close if a specific button is clicked, everything else won't close it.

I currently have the modal opening on page load.

Modal HTML:

```
<div class="reveal" id="first_open_modal" data-reveal data-options="closeOnClick:false; closeOnEsc: false;">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Contact Info</h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- First Name -->
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <p>First Name</p>
                <input type="text" id="first_name_input">
            </div>

            <!-- Last Name -->
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <p>Last Name</p>
                <input type="text" id="last_name_input">
            </div>

            <!-- Phone -->
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <p>Phone</p>
                <input type="text" id="phone_input">
            </div>

            <!-- Email -->
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <p>Email</p>
                <input type="email" id="email_input">
            </div> 
        </div>

        <h3 class='last'>School Info</h3>
        <p>After selecting a school, the modal will close and you can begin picking your colors.</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- School Name -->
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <p>School Name</p>
                <!-- <select id="school_input"></select> -->
                <input type="hidden" id="school_input">
            </div> 
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Select2 / Javascript:

```
// Open Modal
$('#first_open_modal').foundation('open');

// Enable Select2
$("#school_input").select2({
    placeholder: "Lookup a school...",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: 'http://services.sidearmsports.com/services/globalopponentlookup.ashx',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: function (term) {
            return { school_name: term };
        },
        onselect: function () {
            alert("test");
        },
        results: function (data) {
            var schools = data.schools || [];

            return {
                results: $.map(schools, function (v, i) {
                    return { id: v.school_id, text: v.school_name };
                })
            };

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Select2 was adding `.close` which would close both the select and the foundation reveal. I solved it by chaining:

```
.on("close", function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
})
```

onto the select2.